# Android java.lang.VerifyError?

Tags: java, android

На студийном эмуляторе Nexus One с `android 4.2.2` и `api 17` всё работает, а на на планшете Asus K012 с `android 5.0` и `api 21` вот такая ересь:

```
05-09 08:35:32.204 12166-12166/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.studio.morpheus.morpheusholodos, PID: 12166
                                               java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.studio.morpheus.morpheusholodos.MainMenu because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.studio.morpheus.morpheusholodos.MainMenu' appears in /data/app/com.studio.morpheus.morpheusholodos-2/base.apk)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2217)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Я читал в интернетах про эту проблему. Люди, у которых она возникала, описывали её невероятно заумными словами, которые я даже прочитать не смог, а решения им предлагали ещё менее внятные. Но моя программа не из тех, про которую можно сказать что-то такое, в ней всё предельно просто. За что мне это?

**UPD Всё, что есть в коде, в упрощённом варианте**

```
Button blahblahbut;
 public  static String[]blahblah= new String[666];
 public  static Drawable[]blahblahblah= new Drawable[666];
 public  static Drawable[]blahblahblah2= new Drawable[666];
 public static String[][] blaaahblah= new String[666][];
 SharedPreferences prefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    String[] otherblahblah={"some","items","..."};
    blahblah[0]=this.getString(R.string.somestring);
    blaaahblah[0]=otherblahblah
    blahblahblah[0]=ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.петросян_точка_жпг, null);
    System.arraycopy(blahblahblah, 0, blahblahblah2, 0, blahblahblah.length);
    StringTokenizer getsomemoreblahblah= new StringTokenizer(blahblah[0],"•");
    blahblah[0]=getsomemoreblahblah.nextToken().replace("\n", "");
    blahblahbut.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.blahblahbut:
            Intent blahintent= new Intent(this, blahblahactivity.class);
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
            builder.setTitle("Бла бла бла!")
                    .setMessage("Что ж тут может не работать?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Хз :(",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainMenu.this);
            if (prefs.getString(blahblah[0], "").isEmpty) {blahintent.putExtra("blahblah",blahblah);startActivity(blahintent);}else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не бла бла :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            break;
```

Comment: Так уж получилось, что здесь в основном тоже не могут, как и вы,  читать невероятно заумные слова вроде шта. Попробуйте описать свою проблему простым понятным языком.

Comment: @pavlofff Ну я описал: "На студийном эмуляторе Nexus One с android 4.2.2 и api 17 всё работает, а на на планшете Asus K012 с android 5.0 и api 21 вот такая ересь:" 
Что ещё я могу рассказать про происходящее? ;O

Comment: Для начала удалите содержимое папок ./build и ./app/build и попробуйте снова. Какой JDK используете? Не 1.8 часом? Если да, попробуйте на 1.7. А вообще, нужно больше информации.

Comment: @VAndrJ, попробовал, не помогло. Какую ещё информацию я могу предоставить?

Comment: А нет ли случаем у вас synchronized внутри try-catch блока? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30455163

Comment: Можете привести минимальный код класса MainMenu, который всё ещё хватает проблему? Например, не кидает ли конструктор какое-нибудь checked исключение

Comment: @yeputons, обновил

Comment: @yeputons, ну я не мог не прочитать про этот нюанс перед сознанием вопроса. К сожалению, нет, моя проблема в чём-то другом.

Comment: Ну... Ещё предлагают порезать длинные методы на части, разбив на подметоды. Ещё советуют проверить используется стандартная ява или опенсорсная.

Comment: Попробуйте разбить все комманды по отдельным методам. Пишут, что при перегрузке метода тяжелыми объектами, большим кол-вом переменных такое возникает

Comment: И ещё попробуйте вот эту некомпилируемую строку `prefs.getString(blahblah[0], "").isEmpty` заменить на `TextUtils.isEmpty(prefs.getString(blahblah[0], ""))`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, > Ещё предлагают порезать длинные методы на части, разбив на подметоды.
Вот это то, что нужно! А то у меня этих blahblah'ов на самом деле 666 штук. Разбил на пустоты, всё заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @iamsolame, я описал это решение и несколько других в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов того, почему падает может быть много, так же как и вариантов решения. Вот что можно попробоать:

1. Порезать длинные методы на части, разбив на подметоды, т.к. ява может не переварить обилие сущностей, кои надо хранить в памяти (локальные переменные, например)
2. Может помочь удаление содержимого папок ./build и ./app/build вручную. Ибо, возможно, студия сама не смогла их почистить и новые изменения в коде конфликтуют с закешированными.
3. Также падать может из-за `synchronized` внутри `try-catch` блока. Решение - вынести `synchronized` за пределы `try-catch`.
4. Также проверьте, что вы используете не опенсорсную и не 8 яву, ибо, возожно, вы пытаетесь вызвать класс/метод из них, а в андроидовой яве таких нет. Решение - использовать JDK 1.7 от Oracle

Answer (score 1):

> Ещё предлагают порезать длинные методы на части, разбив на подметоды – ЮрийСПб

Вот такое решение. Кто столкнётся с подобной проблемой - знайте.